# Magento2 remove some addresses on checkout page when selecting shipping address

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-address

When i create account in magento2 when i add billing and shipping address in the address book that are different, i want on checkout page on shipping step in the shipping address i want to hide the billing address, or hide the ship hire button.

[image]